# What is the correct pronunciation of "sai"?

Tags: the-dark-tower, pronunciation

In the *Dark Tower* series, what is the official way to pronounce the word "sai"? The two possibilities that come to mind are

- As in "sigh"
- As in "say"

Or maybe as none of the above. It appears that the word is pronounced once in the *Dark Tower* movie, sounding like "say", but it is not clear whether the movie should be accepted as canon.

Usually Oy's speech is useful as a pronunciation guide, but I cannot recall whether he ever says "sai" or a part of it throughout the books.

Comment: Contraction of si(re).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### As in "sigh".

The same question was asked on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheDarkTower/comments/2tpsdg/how_do_you_pronounce_thankeesai/), and the answer was confirmed by multiple people, including with reference to the audiobook (narrated by George Guidall and Frank Muller). One Redditor also justifies this claim by saying:

> Take the "er" out of "sire."

Which makes sense as a possible out-of-universe etymology for the word. (Cf. "ser" in the *A Song of Ice and Fire* books being pronounced the same as "sir", rather than like "sair".)